# When installing React Native Testing Library on an Expo project (uses React 18) I get an error

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-testing-library, react-18

I have an Expo App (the last expo which uses React 18) that I want to run some testing on

But when trying to install React Native Testing Library, I get this error:

[image]

I wonder if this error means that it is incompatible with React 18

What do you suggest me to do?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using:

npm install --save-dev @testing-library/react-native --legacy-peer-deps